# Solving Differential $ \frac{dy}{dt} = k(Ay-1) $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, solution-verification

Let A and k be positive constants. Which of the following is a solution to the given function $$ \frac{dy}{dt} = k(Ay-1) $$

A. $ y = A + Ce^{-kt} $

B. $ y = -A + Ce^{kt} $

C. $ y = A + Ce^{kt} $

D. $ y = A^{-1} + Ce^{Akt} $

E. $ y = -A + Ce^{-kt} $

F. $ y = A^{-1} + Ce^{-Akt} $

Here is what I have done:
$$\int \frac{dy}{Ay-1} = \int k dt $$
$ \frac{1}{A}ln|(Ay-1)| = kt +C $

$ Ay-1 = Ce^{Akt} $

$ y = A^{-1} + Ce^{Akt}$

Could you help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong? I see that (D) matches your answer.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Thank you! To be honest, it is an online problem with just 2 tries. I messed up the first attempt, so before submitting this try I was hoping to get feedback.

Comment: always be confident in your answers. each step is correct in your answer and so no way to be it incorrect. cheer up!! @Sofia